# Populate a select list with AngularJS from a response in JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, getjson

I would like to download a response on a server in JSON which contains the attribute to populate my select list. I would like to do it with AngularJS and I'm using Angular 2.
Nothing appears, I think the problem is on my attribute ng-repeat :

```
<div id="myDiv">

  <div ng-app="d3DemoApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="n in filters track by $index">
        {{n}}
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is my controller :

```
angular.module('d3DemoApp',[])
    .controller('myCtrl',function($scope) {
        $scope.notes = userService.getData();
        //Create and append select list
        var selectList = document.createElement("select");
        selectList.setAttribute("id", "releaseFilter");
        myDiv.appendChild(selectList);
        selectList.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
        selectList.setAttribute("onclick", "myFunction()");

        //Create and append the options
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.notes.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
            option.text = $scope.notes[i];
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        }
});
```

This is the service which should download the response :

```
app.service("userService",["$http",
    function($http) {
        _this = this;
        this.getData = function() {
        },
            $http.get('./dataOnServer.json'). // This adress is normally an HTTP adress which send me the JSON
            success(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
    }
]);
```

This is an online example of the problem with Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/du7sU8bhg2G3X7HckbV9?p=preview

I hope you will can help me, thanks a lot !

Comment: Your Plunker does not work.

Comment: Yes It's an online example of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would point out that you are repeating `filters` when you are not defining such variable in your scope or anywhere? You should probably repeat `$scope.notes` so it would go like this:

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <div ng-app="d3DemoApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="n in notes track by $index">
        {{n}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

And you can do a select like this:

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="n in notes">{{n.value}}</option>
</select>
```

And your JSON is invalid. It should be like this for the repeat:

```
[{value: "value 1"},{value: "value 2"},{value: "value 3"}]
```

Comment: The select is created but the data are not downloaded. You can check the Plunker. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Sorry I didn't take a look at what kind of values your json had. But I edited my answer so that you should use {{n.value}} in your case and set valid JSON. I just posted a more generic answer at first.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I have a question, is possible to use `<option ng-repeat="n in notes">{{n.something}}</option>` ? Because my JSON has no key ! EDIT : I just see your edit... So my response is just an array. How to adapt the code to make it works ?

Comment: You should be able to just use `<option ng-repeat="n in notes">{{n}}</option>`. I can't really test this in your case because your Plunker does not work. It's missing depencies.